# C# Calculate Monthly Payments and show the Whole Dates for Payment opportunity in Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I created an easy calculate Loan without Amorzation but I could not show detail LoanPayment in dataGridView

Letsay today is 2019-03-04 And Loan time begin to tick ...
I have those Information:

```
decimal LoanAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtLoanAmount.Text.Trim());
decimal period = Convert.ToDecimal(txtYears.Text.Trim()); // Years
decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(txtRate.Text.Trim());
```

Letsay period is 5 years

Becouse today is 2019-03-04 then I have to calculate those days within the same month I mean 
between 2019-03-04 and 2019-03-31. I want the Customer will pay back every month of last date. I mean first pay will be 2019-03-31
secondtime pay date 2019-04-30 , thirdtime pay date 2019-05-31 and so on ... until LoanAmount is 0 (ziro).

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Now;
int day = Convert.ToInt32(mydate.Day.ToString());
int restOfdays = days - day; // This givs me offcourse 27 Days
```

So now I can calculate for those days between 2019-03-04 and 2019-03-31

```
decimal Days = period * 12 * 30; // Years in days
decimal RateByDays = rate / (100*12*30); // Rate for day
decimal LoanByDays = LoanAmount / Days; //Loan amount divided with days
decimal payAmountByDays = LoanAmount*RateByDays +LoanByDays;
decimal payAmountByMonths = Decimal.Round(payAmountByDays * 30);
decimal payRestOfMonthDays = Decimal.Round(payDays*restdays); // between 2019-03-04 and 2019-03-31
```

Letsay LoanAmount is 500000 , Rate is 3% and Period 2 years
What I want is to show on dataGridView all payment plane from the begining of Loan date until All money is paid back I mean LoanAmount is ziro so customer knows how much and when or witch date he/she will pay. A list for hole payment period. Like this .

```
Date        AmountToPay
2019-03-31  19875 // this is for those between days , 27 days
2019-04-30  22083
2019-05-31  22083
2019-06-30  22083
And so on until 2 years
2021-02 or 03 depends when LoanAmount will be ziro.
```

I'am trying to do like this but I know I'am wrong

```
public class PaymentTimeTable
{
   public DateTime payDate { get; set; }
   public decimal AmountToPayByMonth { get; set; } 
   public int TermOfYears { get; set; } 
}

public void Calculate(DateTime DateOfPay, decimal amountToPayByMonth, int term)
 {
    int paymentOpportunity = term * 12; // How many times or how many months will customer pay
     List<PaymentTimeTable> payList = new List<PaymentTimeTable>();

      for(int i = 0; i < paymentOpportunity; i++)
          {
                    // I dont know how to formulate here too .....
          }

  }
```

I know I have complicated it more than it should be, but I do not know how to. Please Help !

Comment: The formula is Interest= N * (1 + R/X)^Y where N = Amount, R=Rate, X=days,Y = Time.  Assume 360 days a year.  So Rate/X=.05/360.  Then Assume each month is 30 days =Y.  Then each month N decrements by payment.  A trick for doing the table is to work backwards and assume N = 1.  The last month I(N) = (1+.05/360).  Then I(N-1)= I(N)(1+.05/360). Then I(N-2)=I(N-1)(1+.05/306).  Then I(N-3)=I(N-2)(1+.05/360).  5 Years * 12 payments a year is 60 payments so repeat 60 times.  So if the loan is $500 the total payments P= (500*60)+500*I(N) wherre N = 60.  The each payment is P/60.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your response. Waw ...nice formula. But How can I show practicaly in my datagridView. I'am new for this kind of staffs, please write your code. I would appricate if you can help. Thank you again.

Comment: Create a DataTable:             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Payment", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now, 1.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now, 2.00 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now, 3.00 });  Then datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @jdweng I Think I have to make for loop for every month until Loan is ziro or let say if period is 2 year then 2*12 24 times loop. Then this shows me all Three with the same dates and without how much they will pay every month. Thank you Jdweng

Comment: Yes you have to fill the table with each month values.  I just showed how to create a table and add rows.

Comment: @jdweng I'am confused, I can't make it .... ;)

Comment: Try this :            DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime)); 
            dt.Columns.Add("Payment", typeof(decimal));
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now, i + 1 });
            }

Comment: @jdweng thank you. I did like this, double loanAmount = 10000;
            var interest = 5.0;
            var numberOfYears = 5;  var rateOfInterest = interest / 1200;
            var numberOfPayments = numberOfYears * 12;
            var paymentAmount = (rateOfInterest * loanAmount) / (1 - Math.Pow(1 + rateOfInterest, numberOfPayments * -1)); for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPayments; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(i), i + 1 , paymentAmount });
                loanAmount = loanAmount - paymentAmount;
            }Is this right then?